# Width of fieldset issue

Tags: html, css, fieldset

I have this html:

```
<body>
<table align="center" width="50%">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="iconpanel">
                    <img alt="Logo" src="logo.gif">
                    <hr
                        style="border: solid #d3d3d3 1px; height: 3px; background-color: #d3d3d3;">
                    <form>
                        <fieldset id="fieldset">
                            <legend>Personalia:</legend>
                            Name: <input type="text"><br> Email: <input
                                type="text"><br> Date of birth: <input type="text">
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="main"></div>
</body>
```

together with my css:

```
    #iconpanel {
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 2px solid #d3d3d3;
    padding: 20px; 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; 
    align: center;
}

#fieldset {
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 2px solid #d3d3d3;
    padding: 20px; 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; 
    align: center;
}
```

i get this output:

[image]

as you can see the width of my `fieldset` is longer than the parent panel...

That are my first steps with `Css`. Maybe you can help me find the problem.

Thanks a lot

Stefan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `box-sizing: border-box;` to `#fieldset` to get what you want, because now the width of the element will be `100%` + `20px` of `padding` on each side.

With `box-sizing: border-box;` enabled, the CSS wil try to implement the padding *inside* the set width, so the width is 20px + ? = 100%;

> **border-box**
>   The width and height properties include the padding and border, but
>   not the margin. This is the box model used by Internet Explorer when
>   the document is in Quirks mode. Note that padding and border will be
>   inside of the box e.g.  .box {width: 350px; border: 10px solid black;}
>   leads to a box rendered in the browser of width: 350px. The content
>   box can't be negative and is floored to 0, making it impossible to use
>   border-box to make the element disappear.

Read more about `box-sizing` at [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).